# How can i compare strings in a tuple that is inside a list

Tags: python, string

I have this list of tuples `[(amount, name)]`:

```
[(214.05, 'Charlie'), (153.57, 'Ben'),(213.88, 'Charlie')]
```

I am trying to compare them by their names and if there is a tuple that has the same name, I want to add the amounts together.

The output would go into another list with the same structure `[(amount,name)]`.

I managed to extract the name part with this:

```
for i in range(0, len(spendList)):
    print(spendList[i][1])
```

The output:

```
Charlie
Ben
Charlie
```

How can I compare the names with each other?

Comment: Instead of printing the name, just access the second element (`spendList[i][2]`), add it to another external variable, remove the element `spendList[i]` and add a new element, with the external variable as its amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do these sorts of operations is to use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) like:

#### Code:

```
data = [(214.05, 'Charlie'), (153.57, 'Ben'), (213.88, 'Charlie')]
summed = {}
for amount, name in data:
    summed.setdefault(name, []).append(amount)
summed = [(sum(amounts), name) for name, amounts in summed.items()]
print(summed)
```

#### How does this work?

1. Start by defining a `dict object` to accumulate the amounts for each name.

   ```
    summed = {}
   ```
2. Step through every pair of amounts and names:

   ```
    for amount, name in data:
   ```
3. Using the `dict` property that things that hash the same will end up in the same slot in dict, and the `dict` method: [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to make sure that the dict has an empty list available for every name we come across, create a list of amounts for each name:

   ```
    summed.setdefault(name, []).append(amount)
   ```

   This creates a dict of lists like:

   ```
    {'Charlie': [214.05, 213.88], 'Ben': [153.57]}
   ```
4. Finally using a [`comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) we can `sum()` up all of the items with the same name.

   ```
    summed = [(sum(amounts), name) for name, amounts in summed.items()]
   ```

#### Results:

```
[(427.93, 'Charlie'), (153.57, 'Ben')]
```

Comment: May i ask you to explain this `for amount, name in data:
    summed.setdefault(name, []).append(amount)
summed = {name: sum(amounts) for name, amounts in summed.items()}` for me in a simple way to understand. I am fairly new to python.  @Stephen Rauch

Comment: Sure, I will expand.

Comment: what if the names are in the list like  `[(214.05, ['Charlie','Tom']), (153.57, ['Ben','Harry']), (213.88, ['Charlie','Ben'])]

Answer (score 3):

```
text = [(214.05, 'Charlie'), (153.57, 'Ben'),(213.88, 'Charlie')]
dictionary = {}
for val in text:
    amount, name = val
    if name in dictionary:
        dictionary[name] += amount
    else:
        dictionary[name] = amount
print(*dictionary.items(),sep="\n")
>>('Charlie', 427.93)
  ('Ben', 153.57)
```

Comment: May i ask what the `*` meant in `print(*dictionary.items(),sep="\n")`

Comment: @Charlieit unpacks the list values.ex: a = [1,2,3,4,5] print(*a,sep="\n") this example print all the values in new lines.

Answer (score 2):

First sort your list, then use `itertools.groupby` with a small lambda function:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [(214.05, 'Charlie'), (153.57, 'Ben'),(213.88, 'Charlie')]
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])

for k,v in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x[1]):
    amount = sum(x[0] for x in v)
    print("Name: {}, Amount: {}".format(k, amount))
```

Which yields

```
Name: Ben, Amount: 153.57
Name: Charlie, Amount: 427.93
```

Or, even shorter with a ***dict comprehension***:

```
summary = {name: amount 
            for name, v in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x[1])
            for amount in [sum(x[0] for x in v)]}

print(summary)
# {'Charlie': 427.93, 'Ben': 153.57}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group the amounts per name with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then sum the amounts at the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [(214.05, 'Charlie'), (153.57, 'Ben'),(213.88, 'Charlie')]

d = defaultdict(list)
for amount, name in data:
    d[name].append(amount)

print([(_, sum(v)) for _, v in d.items()])
# [('Charlie', 427.93), ('Ben', 153.57)]
```